# place the USB cable from my hard drive in the middle of the USB connector on the motherboard

Tags: hard-drive, usb, connector

today I was plugging my external hard drive wd elements portable into the usb connector of my computer (on the back in the motherboard) as usual, I thought I had put it well, since it turned on but was not detected by the computer, instead I had put it in the middle hitting only the power pins and not the data ones in the center, moving the usb cable further in was recognized. Now I wanted to ask if there is a chance of damaging the hard drive if it is not connected properly by hitting all 4 pins, but if it only hits the 2 power pins is there any risk of data loss? I'm just asking to be sure, because I'm pretty paranoid about these things

Comment: Are you not using the correct connector? Your description says not.  Try the external drive in a standard computer setup and see if it is recognized.

Comment: it works well, it never gave me any problems. Except that I didn't plug in my hard disk cable all the way, and since it was half in it wasn't recognized by windows. Just a question of curiosity if the hard disk is hit only by the 2 power pins and starts but does not carry data, there is a risk of data loss?

Comment: yes, i using the original correct connector of my hard disk

Comment: absolutely horribly worded title

Comment: You seriously think that if you didn't plug a USB male connector in 100% dead central with complete precision, then it will damage a hard drive?  And you think that there'd be no google results about that problem? And this is when USB has been around for 20ish years+.

Comment: Also it's a fault that the  connector doesn't fit in snugly.

Comment: What do you mean, I shouldn't have asked? it is too stupid a question, I asked just for safety since there is no answer, but there is an article that talks about it that this method can be used to recharge the phone without connecting the sd card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... Except that I didn't plug in my hard disk cable all the way, and
> since it was half in it wasn't recognized by windows

Thank you for the clarification. Since you did not cross-connect, there should not be any damage to the hard drive.

Just applying voltage by the correct power pins should not damage anything.

Perhaps restart the computer first, then carefully plug in all the way.

That should work.

Comment: thank you so much for the information, i feel safer now for my data
Thanks for your kindness

Comment: i put an upvote, but as i am new it is not shown publicly, however it should be there anyway

Comment: Thank you very much. I do electronic troubleshooting so I was happy to provide my experience.